# Get subfolders if folder name contains # (hash)

Tags: api

I am experiencing difficulties with getting the subfolders and files inside the folder that contains #.

API URL was: `http://site url/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/#2')')/folders`
API response doesn't return any folders or files in it.

Is there any work around this?

Comment: are you using SharePoint online ?

Comment: I am using office365

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we have a new ResourcePath API for that nowadays.

You need to use the `GetFolderByServerRelativePath` endpoint as in the below snippet wherein you pass the encoded value of the folder name:

```
var folderRelativeUrl = "/#2";   // like -  /sites/test/Documents/#2

http://site url/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='" + 
encodeURIComponent(folderRelativeUrl) + "')/Folders
```

Reference - [Supporting % and # in files and folders with the ResourcePath API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/supporting-and-in-file-and-folder-with-the-resourcepath-api)

Answer (score 0):

By using `GetFolderByServerRelativePath` endpoint in `Python` we can achieve and below we are manually replacing `#` into `%23`

```
folderRelativeUrl = "/#2";                                  // like -  /sites/test/Documents/#2
folderRelativeUrl = folderRelativeUrl.replace("#", "%23")  //  like - /sites/test/Documents/%232
f"{URL}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='{folderRelativeUrl}')/Folders"
```